# Summarising the first half of a column

Tags: r

I have an example dataframe:

```
a <- c("08/11/2012 15:45","08/11/2012 15:51",
       "09/11/2012 09:02","10/11/2012 15:45",
       "14/11/2012 15:45")  
b <- c(1:5)  
df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to use a summary-type function to inform me which unique dates I have in my df1.  Is there a way of using a function that only looks at a part of a column? (i.e. the date not the time).  For example, using the example above, R would report:

```
08/11/2012
09/11/2012
10/11/2012
14/11/2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted Roland's answer because it gave you what you requested, but I'm not sure it gives you what is needed for most effective use of R's facilities. You should be converting your date-time input into date-time objects and then extracting from them what you need. You should also be learning to use dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format because they will be less ambiguous for you, your clients, and any collation functions that you may employ.

```
?strptime # for input of datetime variable
?strftime # for formatting output of datetime variables
a <- c("08/11/2012 15:45","08/11/2012 15:51",
        "09/11/2012 09:02","10/11/2012 15:45",
        "14/11/2012 15:45")  
 b <- c(1:5)  
 df1 <- data.frame(a=strptime(a, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") ,b)
 unique(strftime(df1$a, format="%d/%m/%Y") )
#[1] "08/11/2012" "09/11/2012" "10/11/2012" "14/11/2012"
```

In answer to the question about how to split by unique dates, I would create a list with the split function:

```
spl.dfrm <- split(df1,  strftime(df1$a, format="%d/%m/%Y") )
```

You can access indivdial dataframe elements either by numer or by name. The names will be the character values of the format operation, so the first one would be:

```
spl.dfrm[["08/11/2012"]]
```

Comment: Many thanks @DWin for the suggestion.  I have now done this and want to subset my original dataframe by these unique dates (i.e. so my file is now in four parts).  I tried df2 <- subset(df1,a=="2012-11-08") - but this is not working.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Many thanks for that @DWin  that's perfect. If I had the original dataframe (Df1), and I wanted to get rid of rows that were after a certain time (i.e. 11/11/2012 15:47), how would I do this?  I would want the very last value of the dataframe to be deleted (leaving the first 4 observations).

Comment: It is possible to do numerical comparsisons with datetime objects, so either saying `df1[ df1$a1 < df1$a1[5] , ]` or calculating a reference datetime value: `df1[ df1$a1 < strptime("11/11/2012 15:47", format= "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), ]` . The first argument to "[" is often an expression that returns a logical vector.

Comment: Thanks for this - its perfect @DWin!  As we are going to have to do this process > 1000 times, I was wonderding whether there was any way of R automating this process - splitting and then exporting all the dataframes that are unique days for each file?

Comment: I don't exactly understand. If the question is how to retrieve unique dates from text files, there are lots of worked examples showing how to loop through all the files in a directory or all the files that match a pattern and applying some process or another. If the first column of all text files were the dates it could be as simple as: `dts<-lapply(list.files(), function(fil) unique(read.table(fil)[[1]])))`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to Date variable:

```
unique(as.Date(df1$a,"%d/%m/%Y"))
#[1] "2012-11-08" "2012-11-09" "2012-11-10" "2012-11-14"

format(unique(as.Date(df1$a,"%d/%m/%Y")),"%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "08/11/2012" "09/11/2012" "10/11/2012" "14/11/2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. In your example you can do

```
unique(sub('^(../../....).*', '\\1', df1$a))
```